# Ubuntu wifi option disappears in Ubuntu20.04 + Windows10

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, 20.04

My PC has dual operating system(ubuntu20.04 + windows10) on two hard disks. Ubuntu's wifi option will lost every time when win10 is started. `rfkill list`shows neither soft nor hard block on wifi module:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The wifi option ***will be back*** if **bcmwl-kernel-source** is either installed or removed and then reboot.

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get purse bcmwl-kernel-source
```

The result of `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c5598000-c559bfff
```

I wonder why the WIFI option disppear every time win10 is logged in. And how can I skip this (install/uninstall + reboot) process when I need to use ubuntu's wifi?

Comment: Is the hybrid shutdown disabled in Win 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bcmwl-kernel-source` is completely unrelated to the problem. You have an Intel device, not a Broadcom.

Disable Windows Fast Startup feature. With the feature enabled, it doesn't shutdown hardware properly.

Comment: That really works! Thanks for your sharing.